# Erro CS0246 ao criar uma nova aplicação asp.net mvc core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core

Estou com um problema, ao criar um novo projeto asp.net-core no visual studio 2017 aparece o seguinte erro ao compilar:

> Erro    CS0246 O nome do tipo ou do namespace "System" não pode ser
>   encontrado(está faltando uma diretiva using ou uma referência de
>   assembly?)    WebApplication2
>   D:\ProjetoTeste\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\Program.cs

Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Consegui a solução em [outro post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42742586/system-could-not-be-found-visual-studio-2017-asp-net-core-project)

Answer (score 0):

Conforme documentação da microsoft: [Erro CS0246](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0246) este erro ocorre quando uma referencia não é encontrada. Neste caso, verifique se o namespace *System*
 foi declarado: `using System`

Comment: A referência **using System** foi adicionada e o problema é justamente nela, o erro acima se refere a ela, aparentemente não está encontrado essa namespace, não consegui encontrar algo relevante na internet sobre isso.

'using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;'